# How to match methods without a specific category

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, qregexp

I need to remove some tests from several classes without some specific category

how do I match than?

in this example i want to remove only the methods 'Bar' and 'BarTwo'

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some Stuff
    /// </summary>
    public class MyClass
    {
        [CategoryA]
        public void Foo()
        {
        }

        public void Bar()
        {
        }

        [CategoryA]
        public void Baz()
        {
        }

        public void BarTwo()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
(?<!]\s)public\s+void[^[]+(?=\[|\s*}\s*}$)
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c!%5d%5cs*)public+void%5b%5e%5b%5d%2b(%3f%3d%5c%5b%7c%5cs*%7d%5cs*%7d%24)&i=namespace+MyNameSpace%0d%0a%7b%0d%0a++++%2f%2f%2f+%3csummary%3e%0d%0a++++%2f%2f%2f+Some+Stuff%0d%0a++++%2f%2f%2f+%3c%2fsummary%3e%0d%0a++++%5bTestClass%5d%0d%0a++++public+class+MyClass%0d%0a++++%7b%0d%0a++++++++%5bCategoryA%5d%0d%0a++++++++public+void+Foo()%0d%0a++++++++%7b%0d%0a++++++++%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++public+void+Bar()%0d%0a++++++++%7b%0d%0a++++++++%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a++++++++%5bCategoryA%5d%0d%0a++++++++public+void+Baz()%0d%0a++++++++%7b%0d%0a++++++++%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a+public+void+Bar()%0d%0a++++++++%7b%0d%0a++++++++%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a++++%7d%0d%0a%7d&o=m)

**Note1 :** I assumed all your methods start with `public` if not you can use the following:

```
(?<!]\s*)(public|private|protected)\s+void[^[]+(?=\[|\s*}\s*}$)
```

**Note2 :** I also assumed that there wont be any `[` or `]` in your methods.

Comment: This will not do a good job if the method is last in the file. Or it there is `]` inside the method body.

Comment: My methods have a diversive number of caracteres like '}' or  ']' or ')' and besides maybe one of these methods can be the last one of the class. the tests initialize some collections to compare with a output from a method

Comment: @RaoniZacaron updated the answer for handling methods at the end.. but if you have methods with `[` and `]`.. the problem cannot be solved with pure regex.

Comment: @stribizhev yeah.. updated considering your first comment.. and AFAIK this cannot be solved with pure regex if method is very diversive.. thats why added `Note2`.. :)